# Message forwarding in Smalltalk

Tags: oop, smalltalk, abstraction, squeak

So I'm writing an application where one object has a bunch of delegate objects that it forwards messages to. The idea is that I can say

```
someObject sendMessage:aMessage
```

and aMessage will be sent to all of someObject's delegates (for any value of aMessage). The only way I've been able to do this is something like:

```
sendMessage:aMessage

| sel chunks kwords arglist msg |
chunks := aMessage findTokens:' '.
kwords := Array new:(chunks size).
arglist := Array new:(chunks size).
1 to: (chunks size) do: [:i | 
    kwords at:i put:((chunks at:i) findTokens:':') at:1.
    arglist at:i put:((chunks at:i) findTokens:':') at:2].
sel := ''.
kwords do:[:word | sel := sel,word,':'].

msg := Message selector:sel arguments:arglist.
delegates do:[:del | del perform:msg selector with:msg arguments].
```

It works, but there has to be a better way. This solution limits the arguments to being strings, and is just plain ugly. Does anyone know a cleaner, better way to forward messages?

BTW, I'm using squeak, but an implementation-independent solution would be prefered ;)

**EDIT**: I should add that the delegates are of the same class as the object, so I can't just override DoesNotUnderstand:.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to pass objects in as arguments, you'll have to pass them in as a separate list of using a message pattern like the following:

> someObject sendMessage: aSelector withArguments: argumentList

Then you'd implement #sendMessage:withArguments: as:

> sendMessage: aSelector withArguments: argumentList
>
> delegates do:[:del |
>     del perform: aSelector withArguments: :argumentList].

and you'd be able to forward arbitrarily complex messages using real objects as args:

> | arguments |
>
> arguments := Array 
>      with: Object new 
>      with: 1234.5 
>      with: ('key'->'value').
>
> someObject sendMessage: #foo:bar:baz: withArguments: arguments

I think this is portable to most dialects as well...

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing this (it will only forward messages that aren't understood by the object that *has* the delegates):

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage 
    delegates
        do: [:delegate | aMessage sendTo: delegate]
```

You could construct Message objects explicitly like:

```
msg := Message selector: #foo arguments: #(bar baz)
"then use them like:"
anObject perform: msg selector with: msg arguments
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the object is of the same type as the delegates, so I can't do that. I added that to the original question.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a new class for this delegate collection and then use doesNotUnderstand?  Without doing more explicit message creation it's probably the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

In Squeak, see the class ObjectTracer.  You can use it to intercept all message sends to an Object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing what aMessage is, and since you mentioned all your delegate objects are of the same class, I'd do something like:

```
MyobjectClass>>SendMessage: aMessage

   self doSomethingUsefulOnThisInstanceIfApplicable: aMessage.
   self dependents do: [:ea | ea SendMessage: aMessage ] .
```

You may also want to look to see if using any of the following messages could work for you: (these are from Cincom VisualWORKS)

```
update: 
update:with:
update:with:from:
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a polymorphism, that is, implement this method in class of each object you are calling? Then you implement in your object method with the same name, which just delegates a call to all subobjects. Something like:

```
MyObjectClass>>someMethod
subobjects do: [:each | each someMethod]
```

Comment: This won't work because (as noted in a later edit) the object is of the same class as its delegates.