# Nodejs: __call implementation available?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I need at least such feature atm:

```
function ExampleClass() {
}

ExampleClass.prototype.__noSuchMethod__ = function() {
  console.log("No such method, maybe you should try reading the docs?");
}

example = new ExampleClass();
example.eatPizza();
```

Isn't it implemented yet in v8 or anyhow emulated else?

Have anyone implemented such feature on their projects?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture method missing in Javascript and do some logic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283362/capture-method-missing-in-javascript-and-do-some-logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar question on StackOverflow, you can find the answer there:

[Capture method missing in Javascript and do some logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283362/capture-method-missing-in-javascript-and-do-some-logic)