# Can I use Interceptors in Chakra

Tags: javascript, chakra

Can I use Interceptors in a native c++ application that's embedding Chakra?

I want a callback to my application, when javascript code like `session.id = 5` is executed. The session variable is not previously declared.
The callback will return an valid JsValueRef to the engine.

I know that this is possible in the google V8 engine, using named and indexed propertyGetter/Setter. However for my project, i need the JIT aspect of chakra, which v8 fails to deliver for me. So can someone tell me if something analogue is possible in Chakra?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture method missing in Javascript and do some logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283362/capture-method-missing-in-javascript-and-do-some-logic)